# How can I make a field readonly from fields_view_get in OpenERP7?

Tags: openerp-7

What I want:

Based on two context variables which must BOTH exist (one default value, and a flag), I must make a field readonly. If either of the context variables is not present, the field should be editable as usual.

I have this file:

```
from osv import fields, osv
from lxml import etree


class ir_sequence(osv.osv):
    _name = 'ir.sequence'
    _inherit = 'ir.sequence'

    def fields_view_get(self, cr, uid, view_id=None, view_type='form', context=None, toolbar=False, submenu=False):
        """
        We set the field to readonly depending on the passed flags. This means:
           * We must specify to fix the sequence type (fixed_sequence_type=True).
           * We must specify a default value for the "code" (default_code=my.custom.seq.code).

        This only applies to context (e.g. a context node in a ir.action.act_window object, or a <field /> tag for a
           relational field to this object, with a context with these values).
        """
        res = super(ir_sequence, self).fields_view_get(cr, uid, view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type,
                                                       context=context, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)
        context = context or {}
        is_fixed = context.get('fixed_sequence_type', False) and bool(context.get('default_code', False))
        if is_fixed and 'code' in res['fields']:
            res['fields']['code']['readonly'] = 1
            #arch = etree.XML(res['arch'])
            #for node in arch.xpath("//field[@name='code']"):
            #    node.set('readonly', '1')
            #res['arch'] = etree.tostring(arch)

        return res

ir_sequence()
```

And I tried two alternatives to change the readonly attribute of a field to True when a condition was met (condition is given by the `is_fixed` variable - by debugging I see that it gets the True value it needs, when I trigger it in the intended manner).

The first alternative was edit the arch content as XML, find the node for the field 'code', and fix it. The code for that alternative is commented.

The second alternative was edit the fields dictionary, find the 'code' field, and set readonly=True on that field.

Neither of them worked (symptoms: the field is not readonly when the condition evaluates to True).

What must I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
  <field name="field_name" invisible="context.get('flag1',False) and context.get('flag2',False)" />
```

you can pass context to list view using action which is bind to the list view.

```
<record id="action_account_tree1" model="ir.actions.act_window">
   <field name="name">Analytic Items</field>
   <field name="res_model">account.analytic.line</field>
   <field name="view_type">form</field>
   <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
   <field name="context">{'flag1':True,'flag2':True}</field>
</record>
```

You have to manage logical conditions as per your need.

No need to override fields_view_get if your aim is to hide fields from list view based on context then.

Thanks.